# In-app billing - article not found

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I am planning to publish an application with in app billing functionalities. I haven't released the application itself on the playstore yet, but I've activated the in app products. Now when trying to access them via my phone, I get the typical in app purchase window, but saying:

The article You wanted to buy couldn't be found.

Do I have to first publish the application to get the in app billing working or is there some issue with my application?

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago Google made some changes to the testing of *In-App purchases*. Now you need to publish your application first in order to test them. Luckily it's enough if you **publish** your application **as** an **alpha-version**.

> **Note:** You can do end-to-end testing of your app by publishing it to an alpha distribution channel. This allows you to publish the app to the Google Play store, but limit its availability to just the testers you designate.

Read more in the [docs (Testing In-App Billing)](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-test).